# How to pass callback url in client.userInfo tumblr javascript function?

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

I am new to tumblr api and trying to load all blogs related to user using javascript functions. For this i have used tumblr.js from https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js.

i am using below code to get it work.

```
    var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');
    var client = tumblr.createClient({
        consumer_key: 'jonJZTo19butVDvE191XA3ldsWwKkawkIzSrOqxuCo0B8RdE9k',
        consumer_secret: 'rwpF8oZ17JuNr9GpkKKDbSmsb547rKPLxm1eEujgun7hzjyWSz',
        token: 'XUeiaJNW6aD0Ynl0lSHZYofVW7ooFZLj7NmlSGmiClbVC5VPk8',
        token_secret: 'rPs6Upq7R46D8Ei7s8s8tEVT1Qc6ETMUaPzcsp5KUi2tDtHtDN'
    });
    client.userInfo("http://localhost/Default.aspx");
```

But it always throws error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

and if i used client.userInfo(); then i am getting "GET /v2/user/info? 404 (Not Found) " error.

Please help me out of this.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

From the tumblr readme on github (https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js) you can see the following piece of code

```
// Show user's blog names
client.userInfo(function (err, data) {
    data.blogs.forEach(function (blog) {
        console.log(blog.name);
    });
});
```

Notice that the parameter of the `client.userInfo` function is another function, not a string with an url. That function you pass as a param is your callback function, the one which will be executed once the request has been completed. In the example you call also see that the function receives 2 parameters, `err` and `data`. Instead of using a callback url, you should make the call and do some operation in your callback function, like displaying the name of the user's blogs in the console as shown in the example. The `data` param will contain information like

```
"user": {
   "following": 263,
   "default_post_format": "html",
   "name": "derekg",
   "likes": 606,
   "blogs": [
      {
       "name": "derekg",
       "title": "Derek Gottfrid",
       "url": "http://derekg.org/",
       "tweet": "auto",
       "primary": true,
       "followers": 33004929,
      },
      {
       "name": "ihatehipstrz",
       "title": "I Hate Hipstrz",
       ...
      }
    ]
 }
```

which is documented at http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods